# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_44 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNNs, keras and tf. I am trying to build SqueezNet for keras 2.0 as shown here https://github.com/DT42/squeezenet_demo. It didn´t work for me, so I just tried to make only one layer network and again failed. Below is the code for one layer.

As input I use white-black images 90*90 with 2 classes.

I am a bit lost cause I have tried and read many different things and not sure how to fix this.

```
import h5py
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Activation, Concatenate
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K

import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split





class_names = {
        "class_A": 0,
        "class_B": 1
}

#all imgs in one file
X = list()
y = list()

for img_folder in ["class_A", "class_B"]:
    for img in glob.glob("path" + img_folder +  "*.jpg"):
        input_img = cv2.imread(img)
        X.append(input_img)
        y.append(class_names[img_folder])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

input_img = Input(shape=(90,90,1))
b = Dense(32)(input_img)
model = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=b)
print(model.summary())


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=["accuracy"])


model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=20, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: `X_train` must be a numpy array with shape `(any, 90,90,1)`. It seems that your `X_train` is a list.

Comment: X_train=np.array(X_train)
is this enough?

Comment: Or maybe `np.asarray`. But you must verify the shape.